# Karate match command to compare null with empty

Tags: karate

I am calling 2 web services developed by 2 different companies

first service response: `{"abc":"test","xyz":""}`
second service response: `{"foo":"USD","xyz":null}`

Now I want to match the value of xyz from both services using automation. However, one service returns empty, and another returns `null`. Due to this test fails. Is there a way to handle this in karate?

Note: Service response cannot be changed as it's developed by 2 different companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least 5 different ways to do this. Hope this get you thinking about ideas:

```
* def response1 = {"abc":"test","xyz":""}
* def response2 = {"foo":"USD","xyz":null}
* if (response1.xyz == '') response1.xyz = '##string'
* match response2 contains any response1
```

Please see this answer for more examples: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567262/143475