# AND condition in Karate

Tags: karate, assertion

[
{
“X”: “shop”,
"description": “ABC”,
“Y”: {
“Z”: {
“T1”: “1”,
“T2”: “2”}
}
}]

Now need to write a condition in karate that if (T1 == ‘1’ && T2 == ‘2’) then assert that “X” = “shop”
How can we achieve this in a single line or in short way

Tried various methods but did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is certainly very complicated JSON, so I would try to "pre process" it to be simpler.

Here is one possible solution out of many. Please use the hints to arrive at what works for you:

```
* def response = [{ X: 'shop', Y: { Z: { T1: '1', T2: '2' } } }]
* def data = response.map(x => ({ X: x.X, T1: x.Y.Z.T1, T2: x.Y.Z.T2 }))
* def good = data.filter(x => x.T1 == '1' && x.T2 == '2' && x.X == 'shop')
* match data == good
```

Refer here for more hints: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567262/143475