# In Karate, how to write an assertion that when i loop thru belowarray, all the IDs should have name associated to them except for the id "nonexisting"

Tags: karate, assertion

“History: {
“Count”: 6,
"summary": [
{
"id": "5010425959",
"name": "Clothes",
"total_amount": "-105.23"
},
{
"id": “NONEXISTING”,
"total_amount": "-3307.03"
},
{
"id": "5010425965",
"name": "Cell Phone",
"total_amount": "196.22"
},
{
"id": "5010425964",
"name": "Dogs",
"total_amount": "454.40"
},
{
"id": "5010425962",
"name": "Coffee",
"total_amount": "25.00"
},
{
"id": "5010425958",
"name": "Entertainment",
"total_amount": "33.48"
},
{
"id": "502304430",
"name": "Groceries",
"total_amount": "109.24"
}
]
}
}

I need to write a condition that if name exists for the id "NONEXISTING" then the TC should fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many way to do this, just giving one option below:

```
* def existing = response.filter(it => it.name)
* match each existing contains { name: '#string' }
* def nonexisting = response.filter(it => it.id == 'NONEXISTING')
```

Refer here if you want more explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62567262/143475